# Etiquette for removing questions which turn out to be bugs

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, etiquette

I asked a question on Stack Overflow but after researching it further I've found out that the problem is caused by a known bug (now resolved but not yet public). Should I delete my question or leave it there in case anybody else hits the same issue? It was pretty difficult for me to find information about the topic.

Comment: (for anybody interested in the specifics, this is the question I'm referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842981/cannot-give-focus-to-flash-object-with-keyboard-but-can-focus-with-javascript)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't remove the question; as you point out it's useful.

Answer your question, link to the bug report, keep it updated when the bug is fixed and detail what you've done to work around the bug (if anything).

Answer (score 12):

As someone who finds these periodically in searches (or from questions) do NOT delete it.

These questions (such as [this one of mine recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688360/why-does-my-spreadsheet-function-behave-differently-than-when-called-from-code)) are unbelievably helpful when searching to resolve problems.

Having a source saying, "you are encountering a bug which is currently not fixed" is such a great find when trying to track down obscure errors.

I can't stress this enough. I've spent hours trying to find information about problems which ultimately turned out to be bugs or quirky behaviors and normally this results in obscure forum threads from years ago with no real explanation or resolution.

Think of this guy:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't delete it. Knowing that something is caused by a bug is as informative as knowing how to avoid the unexpected behavior.